# FATAL: role "root" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I trying to create rails application with postgresql database, but when I create database `rake db:migrate` bash show me an error

```
FATAL:  role "my" does not exist
```

how fix?

sorry for my bad English

**UPD**

```
my@my-P5K-SE ~/ror/timonin $ rake db:create
FATAL:  role "my" does not exist
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:898:in `rescue in connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:88:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:102:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:209:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:101:in `create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"timonin_development"}
FATAL:  role "my" does not exist
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:898:in `rescue in connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:88:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:102:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:209:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:101:in `create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"timonin_test"}
```

database.yml

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: timonin_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  #username: timonin

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: timonin_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: timonin_production
  username: timonin
  password: <%= ENV['TIMONIN_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: What is its backtrace?

Comment: What database user did you use? If you didn't specify any user, psql takes the user you're using at that moment and that could be root. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres

Comment: this is not full trace log, the upper line with excpetion is absent, please add it. then show please the migration file in which the excpetion is thrown

Comment: The corresponding `database.yml` or whatever would be useful.

Comment: Edit question.I didn't understand Which migration file do you mean, schema.rb or what?

Comment: @vveare138 a guess: _does_ `create role "my" login ` _solve your problem_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can connect to Postgres server with explicit (`my` i.e. OS username) or implicit (`timonin` i.e. role in `database.yml`) login.

As I see your `database.yml` has username statement, but **only for production** environment. Running rake tests without specifying Rails environment will run them against *development* environment by default. That is why you have error like `FATAL:  role "my" does not exist`.

So depending on your needs you have to add these statements to all databases' defenitions (`test` and `development` as well):

```
  username: timonin
  password: <%= ENV['TIMONIN_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

After that you Rails application will connect as `timonin` user.

Full checklist is the following:

- **Create role**

Here is SQL for PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE ROLE timonin LOGIN PASSWORD 'Pas$_sword'
  NOINHERIT CREATEDB
   VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
COMMENT ON ROLE timonin
  IS 'Timonin database role for Rails app';
```

- **Uncomment or add statements** `username: timonin` and `password: <%= ENV['TIMONIN_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>` to your database.yml file
- **Run** all operations with `TIMONIN_DATABASE_PASSWORD` variable:

Here is changed rake command:

```
rake db:create TIMONIN_DATABASE_PASSWORD='Pas$_sword'
```

or:

```
rake db:create TIMONIN_DATABASE_PASSWORD='Pas$_sword' RAILS_ENV=test
```

for test environment.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem while using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for my Ruby on Rails installation. The problem was that I had not created a user for my postgres database so I did the following and it worked.

**#1 logged in as default user**
$sudo su postgres

**#2 login into the postgres interactive terminal**
psql

Alternatively, you can combine step #1 and #2 as follows:

$sudo su postgres psql

**#3 View a list of roles while in the postgres interative terminal**
postgres=#  \du

#4 create role in the postgres database
postgres=#  CREATE user  with password '';

**#5 Make the user your have just created a superuser**
postgres=# alter user  with superuser;

**#6 Quit from the postgres console**
postgres=# \q