# rails doesnt connect to postgres via tcp/ip but unix socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

[old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803489/fatal-role-root-does-not-exist-when-running-rake-dbschemaload)

i try to set up a postgres database and run into the following error when executing "rake db:schema:load". So it seems that rails tries to connect to my DB using a unix socket, instead of tcp/ip, which i have configured (refer to my database.yml below). I dont get why this is happening. I stumbled over the following thread, which confirms that i have set up my database.yml correct. [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15306770/revisions). One idea was to change in the postgres config the method: peer for type: local to md5. However, as far as i understand the postgres config, my second line should do the job. Furthermore, another rails app is running on the same server using tcp/ip, so i expect the psql config to be correct. I also compared the database.yml files and they are the same

```
[root@myserver app]# rake db:schema:load                                    
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0166s
-- create_table("qip_changes", {:force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0494s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0539s
-- add_foreign_key("qip_changes", "users")
   -> 0.0037s
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "my_user_name"
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
     # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
     local   all             all                                     peer
     host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
```

database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_db_name
  username: my_user_name
  password: my_password
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_db_name
  username: my_user_name
  password: my_password
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

production:
  <<: *default
  database: my_db_name
  username: my_user_name
  password: my_password
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enter your database information as a url, it will properly connect via tcp/ip. I would love if we didn't have to enter the db info this way as it kind of sucks to look at, and is harder to maintain.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode

development:
  <<: *default
  # Rails 6 requires us to put this in as a url in order to force tcp/ip
  url: postgresql://postgres::example@localhost:5432/dev?pool=5
```